# TimeSeriesSplit in SkLearn is not working propertly

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, cross-validation

TimeSeriesSplitCV is not working properly on sklearn. Is this appropriate behavior?

Using the example given here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
print(tscv)  

for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

When you change the number of splits to 2 instead of the default n_splits = 5, the test data become length 2 and not 1. However, for all time series cases as defined in SKLearn documentation and in most common scenarios, the goal is to predict the next observation in chronological order. Am I misunderstanding something?

```
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
TRAIN: [0 1 2 3] TEST: [4 5]
```

Comment: let me know if you need any additional help

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for your response. Very helpful. I misunderstood the time-series validation strategy and thought from the given example that the test set should always be one. I now see this is similar to K-fold, but simply chronological folds that continuously expand and not random sampling. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Please consider : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the validation set include **only** the next observation is just a special case when you set `n_splits` equal to the `n_samples - 1`, where `n_samples` is the number of samples you have in your dataset.

The official docstring example does exactly that (`n_samples=6` and `n_splits=5`). In general, the validation sets contain more than just 1 sample.

See a more comprehensive example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-cv-indices-py). Below I attach a plot from it. In this case `n_samples=100`, `n_splits=4` and each of the validation (test) sets contains 20 samples.

[image]